# JQuery fullCalendar: problem with modified elements using eventAfterRender

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I wasn't liking the fact that a half-hour event wasn't taking up enough space in my calendar, so I have modified the element using the below code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#CalendarControl").fullCalendar({
        eventAfterRender: function(event, element, view) {
            var halfHour = 60 * 30 * 1000; // in milliseconds
            if((event.end - event.start) <= halfHour){
                element.height(40);
                element.find(".fc-event-time").text($.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.start, "HH:mm") + ' - ' + $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.end, "HH:mm"));
                element.find("A").append("<span class=\"fc-event-title\"></span>")
                element.find(".fc-event-title").text(event.title);
            }
        }
    });
})
```

As you can see, I'm basically making it take up the same space as an hour long event, plus formatted as such.

The only trouble is, that it can now overlap an older event, as the previous auto-overlapping code has already happened (and found itself not required), so I need a way to render the calendar again (WITH my changes)?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So the half hour event takes up an hour's worth of space?  That sounds potentially confusing, since it will look like it ends half an hour later.  If you want to change the size of all events, you could try setting the `defaultEventMinutes` to perhaps 15 (which will make a half hour event take up two slots instead of one) or even 10 (so a half hour event takes up 3 slots).  Of course your hour events will take up more space as well, but this will provide a correct view of the situation to those reading the calendar.

To change the behavior so that you have the calendar respecting artificially large events changed by `eventAfterRender` you're going to have to modify the calendar's collision checking code in the source.

If you want your half hour events to actually *be* hour events, you can call [updateEvent](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/updateEvent/) to make it an hour long event after the fact.  Or just change it in your data source.

Comment: Regarding "modify the calendar's collision checking code", do you know which lines these might be, as I couldn't quite find it in the source?

Comment: @justkt Good thinking on the slotMinutes idea, but that also causes confusion. My events can only be 30 minutes minimum (in 30 minute incremental durations), so the 15 minute slots seems a bit weird. 

You're right, that I'm wanting to give a 30 minute slot a full hour's screen space, but the 30 minute slot displays itself oddly, so I'd prefer the hour format!

Cheers so far though

Comment: @Oxonhammer - it depends on what version you are using.  FullCalendar is a fast-moving plugin that changes pretty regularly.

Comment: @Oxonhammer - for display and rendering purposes, take a look at `compileDaySegs` and `renderDaySegs` in the code.  Personally, though, I wouldn't want to make a half hour event look like an hour event when it wasn't (unless there's something I'm missing).  Sounds confusing.

Comment: I just dislike the way a half hour gets rendered as a single line, with the start time and title on one line. Just looks naff. We might take this out though.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting up a timeout to call "rerenderEvents"?

```
   if((event.end - event.start) <= halfHour) {
     // ... whatever ...
     setTimeout(function() {
       $('#CalendarControl').fullCalendar('rerenderEvents');
     }, 10);
   }
```

Comment: Hi @Pointy, I'm not sure that will work? Surely that'll just go and get the data, and cause the same problem? I could be wrong though?

Comment: Well if you make the changes on the first re-render, then won't the same code on the second time through *not* need to make the same changes again?  Maybe I don't understand what you're trying to do, but if you're fighting against what the plugin thinks it should do then I don't think that will be successful in the end :-)

Comment: Just tried this Pointy, and it's got itself in an infinite loop! You're right though, I am trying to mod the plugin, so perhaps won't be successful. Thought I'd try though ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I was pointed to using eventRender rather than eventAfterRender, which works for me in a slightly different context

For example

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#CalendarControl").fullCalendar({
    eventRender: function(event, jqElement, view) {
      jqElement.height(40);
    }
  }
}
```